# Intersect does not remove features, leaves them empty. Python

Tags: python, intersection, geopandas

So I have a shapefile with 16k linestrings, and one polygon of a smaller area.

My intention is to do intersection and keep only the lines or fragments of lines that lie inside the polygon, following this tutorial: http://geopandas.org/geometric_manipulations.html

This is the output of the geometry of the large shapefile:

```
> network
0        LINESTRING Z (524669.5552664882 6066308.874914
...
16047    LINESTRING Z (735457.2357274202 5693634.842955...
Name: geometry, Length: 16048, dtype: object
```

this the polygon:

```
> shtest_utm geometry 0  POLYGON ((781557.9314549405 5812460.808320792,...
```

This is my code:

```
file = 'test.geojson'
with open(file) as f:
    data = geojson.load(f)
vecfilename = 'strecken_polyline.shp'
pdb.set_trace()
vector = GeoDataFrame.from_file(vecfilename)
vector.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326', 'no_defs': True}
vector_utm = vector.to_crs(epsg = 32632)
shtest = GeoDataFrame.from_features(data["features"])
shtest.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326', 'no_defs': True}
shtest_utm = shtest.to_crs(epsg = 32632)
network = vector_utm['geometry']
network.buffer(20)
network.plot()
shtest['geometry'].plot()
inter = network.intersection(shtest_utm)
```

And the output of inter is:

> inter
>   0        ()
>   ...
>   16047    ()
>   Length: 16048, dtype: object

Is this a normal behavior? I would not expect so. Like that I can not see if there is any line remaining.

Furthermore, .plot() does not work, but that is another problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a GeoSeries of geometries to `network.intersection(..)`, it will try to 'align' the passed series with the calling one, meaning that geopandas will try to take the intersection of the first element in `network` with the first element in the passed series, the second with the second, etc.

In this case you only have a single polygon for which you want to calculate the intersections, therefore you should pass a single polygon object, so geopandas calculates the intersection with this same polygon for all elements in `network`:

```
shtest_utm_polygon = shtest_utm.geometry.iloc[0]
inter = network.intersection(shtest_utm_polygon)
```

Comment: sorry for the superlate reply, somehow I missed you answer.

Unfortunately, I think your answer is not what I am asking. My doubt is why features that not instersect, instead of get removed, appear as empty.